# How to create one function to call multiple ctp file in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I created 12 different functions and 12 different ctp files for showing the value from the database into my webpage using 12 months 12 Tabs LIKE January ... December . I want to show three top values from each month. As per cakephp we created different function for different CTP files. Like for January i created one function name January and created one CTP file name january.ctp and like for rest of 11 months i created different different functions using months name with same month wise CTP files.Just the value of the month($month) is different in each function ,  Is there is any way to write one function and sending variable into the 12 ctp files. How can i make my code more efficient, i added my code below

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use Cake\Core\Configure;
use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry; 

public function january()
{
      $userDetails=Configure::read('userdetails');
      $profile=Configure::read('profile');
      $this->loadModel('Users');
      $usersID = $this->Auth->user('id');
      $profileImageShow=$this->Users->getUploadPath($usersID);
      $categoryTable=TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('categories');
      $results=$categoryTable->find("all")->toList();
      $votes;
      $month  = 01;
      $year=date("Y");
      $categoriesArray;

      foreach($results as $result)
      {        
            $votesCount=$this->Sjvotes->find("all",[
                'conditions'=>['month'=> $month,'year'=>$year,'category_id'=>$result->id]])->select(['count' => $this->Sjvotes->find()->func()->count('*')])->group(['user_id','category_id'])->order(['count'=>'desc'])->limit(2)->toList();

            $categoriesArray[]=$result->id;

            $temp=0;
            foreach($votesCount as $key => $count)
            {
               if($temp!=$count->count)
               {
               $userVotes=$this->Sjvotes->find("all", ['conditions'=>['year'=>$year,'category_id'=>$result->id]])->
                select(['count' => $this->Sjvotes->find()->func()->count('*'), 'category_id','user_id','fname'=>'Users.firstname','lname'=>'Users.lastname', 'profile_image'=>'Users.profile_image'])
                ->contain(['Users'])
                ->group(['user_id','category_id'])
                ->having(['count'=>$count->count])
                ->order(['count'=>'desc'])
                ->toList();
                $temp=$count->count;

                if($key==0)
                {
                   $class="gold";
                }else 
                    if($key==1)
                    {
                        $class="silver";
                    }else 
                        {
                            $class="bronz";
                        }

                $votes[$result->id][$class]=$userVotes;
               } 
            }
      }     

        $voteToppers=$this->Sjvotes->find("all", ['conditions'=>['year'=>$year,'category_id in ' =>$categoriesArray]])->
            select(['count' => $this->Sjvotes->find()->func()->count('*'), 'category_id','user_id','fname'=>'Users.firstname','lname'=>'Users.lastname', 'profile_image'=>'Users.profile_image'])
            ->contain(['Users'])
            ->group(['user_id'])
            ->order(['count'=>'desc'])
            ->toList();
        $temp=0;
        $changes=0;
        foreach($voteToppers as $key => $topper)
        {
              if($temp!=$topper->count)
              {
                if($changes==0)
                {
                   $class="gold";
                }else 
                    if($changes==1)
                    {
                        $class="silver";
                    }else 
                        {
                            $class="bronz";
                        }

                    $temp=$topper->count;
                    $changes++;
              }
              if($changes>3)
              {
                break;
              }

              $topUsers[$class][]=$topper;
        }
       $this->set(compact("results"));
       $this->set(compact("votes"));
       $this->set(compact(["topUsers", "userDetails", "profile"]));

}

//For February 

public function february()
{
      $userDetails=Configure::read('userdetails');
      $profile=Configure::read('profile');
      $this->loadModel('Users');
      $usersID = $this->Auth->user('id');
      $profileImageShow=$this->Users->getUploadPath($usersID);
      $categoryTable=TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('categories');
      $results=$categoryTable->find("all")->toList();
      $votes;
      $month  = 02;
      $year=date("Y");
      $categoriesArray;

      foreach($results as $result)
      {        
            $votesCount=$this->Sjvotes->find("all",[
                'conditions'=>['month'=> $month,'year'=>$year,'category_id'=>$result->id]])->select(['count' => $this->Sjvotes->find()->func()->count('*')])->group(['user_id','category_id'])->order(['count'=>'desc'])->limit(2)->toList();

            $categoriesArray[]=$result->id;

            $temp=0;
            foreach($votesCount as $key => $count)
            {
               if($temp!=$count->count)
               {
               $userVotes=$this->Sjvotes->find("all", ['conditions'=>['month'=>$month,'year'=>$year,'category_id'=>$result->id]])->
                select(['count' => $this->Sjvotes->find()->func()->count('*'), 'category_id','user_id','fname'=>'Users.firstname','lname'=>'Users.lastname', 'profile_image'=>'Users.profile_image'])
                ->contain(['Users'])
                ->group(['user_id','category_id'])
                ->having(['count'=>$count->count])
                ->order(['count'=>'desc'])
                ->toList();
                $temp=$count->count;

                if($key==0)
                {
                   $class="gold";
                }else 
                    if($key==1)
                    {
                        $class="silver";
                    }else 
                        {
                            $class="bronz";
                        }

                $votes[$result->id][$class]=$userVotes;
               } 
            }
      }     

        $voteToppers=$this->Sjvotes->find("all", ['conditions'=>['month'=>$month,'year'=>$year,'category_id in ' =>$categoriesArray]])->
            select(['count' => $this->Sjvotes->find()->func()->count('*'), 'category_id','user_id','fname'=>'Users.firstname','lname'=>'Users.lastname', 'profile_image'=>'Users.profile_image'])
            ->contain(['Users'])
            ->group(['user_id'])
            ->order(['count'=>'desc'])
            ->toList();
        $temp=0;
        $changes=0;
        foreach($voteToppers as $key => $topper)
        {
              if($temp!=$topper->count)
              {
                if($changes==0)
                {
                   $class="gold";
                }else 
                    if($changes==1)
                    {
                        $class="silver";
                    }else 
                        {
                            $class="bronz";
                        }

                    $temp=$topper->count;
                    $changes++;
              }
              if($changes>3)
              {
                break;
              }

              $topUsers[$class][]=$topper;
        }
       $this->set(compact("results"));
       $this->set(compact("votes"));
       $this->set(compact(["topUsers", "userDetails", "profile"]));
}

//March 

public function march()
{
      $userDetails=Configure::read('userdetails');
      $profile=Configure::read('profile');
      $this->loadModel('Users');
      $usersID = $this->Auth->user('id');
      $profileImageShow=$this->Users->getUploadPath($usersID);
      $categoryTable=TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('categories');
      $results=$categoryTable->find("all")->toList();
      $votes;
      $month  = 03;
      $year=date("Y");
      $categoriesArray;

      foreach($results as $result)
      {        
            $votesCount=$this->Sjvotes->find("all",[
                'conditions'=>['month'=> $month,'year'=>$year,'category_id'=>$result->id]])->select(['count' => $this->Sjvotes->find()->func()->count('*')])->group(['user_id','category_id'])->order(['count'=>'desc'])->limit(2)->toList();

            $categoriesArray[]=$result->id;

            $temp=0;
            foreach($votesCount as $key => $count)
            {
               if($temp!=$count->count)
               {
               $userVotes=$this->Sjvotes->find("all", ['conditions'=>['month'=>$month,'year'=>$year,'category_id'=>$result->id]])->
                select(['count' => $this->Sjvotes->find()->func()->count('*'), 'category_id','user_id','fname'=>'Users.firstname','lname'=>'Users.lastname', 'profile_image'=>'Users.profile_image'])
                ->contain(['Users'])
                ->group(['user_id','category_id'])
                ->having(['count'=>$count->count])
                ->order(['count'=>'desc'])
                ->toList();
                $temp=$count->count;

                if($key==0)
                {
                   $class="gold";
                }else 
                    if($key==1)
                    {
                        $class="silver";
                    }else 
                        {
                            $class="bronz";
                        }

                $votes[$result->id][$class]=$userVotes;
               } 
            }
      }     

        $voteToppers=$this->Sjvotes->find("all", ['conditions'=>['month'=>$month,'year'=>$year,'category_id in ' =>$categoriesArray]])->
            select(['count' => $this->Sjvotes->find()->func()->count('*'), 'category_id','user_id','fname'=>'Users.firstname','lname'=>'Users.lastname','profile_image'=>'Users.profile_image'])
            ->contain(['Users'])
            ->group(['user_id'])
            ->order(['count'=>'desc'])
            ->toList();
        $temp=0;
        $changes=0;
        foreach($voteToppers as $key => $topper)
        {
              if($temp!=$topper->count)
              {
                if($changes==0)
                {
                   $class="gold";
                }else 
                    if($changes==1)
                    {
                        $class="silver";
                    }else 
                        {
                            $class="bronz";
                        }

                    $temp=$topper->count;
                    $changes++;
              }
              if($changes>3)
              {
                break;
              }

              $topUsers[$class][]=$topper;
        }
       $this->set(compact("results"));
       $this->set(compact("votes"));
       $this->set(compact(["topUsers", "userDetails", "profile"]));

}

//april
```

Comment: DRY (don't repeat yourself)! You need one method (month) and one ctp (month). Pass month names as function arguments or query string. Avoid multiple else if, use switch. Did you understand relations between you db models? If not try draw ERD (use mysql workbench). Check your code styling ```composer cs-check``` and try to fix ```composer cs-fix```., also try phpstan. Use good code editor, vscode is free and very popular. Learn how to write good php / cakephp code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is. Get the current month and then check the current month, then send to that month ctp file according to the current month. Like this -

```
$month = date('M');
if ($month == 'Mar') {
    $this->render('/march');
}
if ($month == 'Jan'){
    $this->render('/jan'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the value of the `$month` variable?

```
public function january() {
    return $this->_month(1, 'January');
}

public function february() {
    return $this->_month(2, 'February');
}

// etc...

protected function _month($month, $monthName) {
    // Existing implementation of each month's function here,
    // except without initializing the $month variable

    $this->set(compact('results', 'votes', 'topUsers', 'userDetails', 'profile', 'month', 'monthName'));
    $this->render('month');
}
```

And rename `january.ctp` to `month.ctp`, and you'll have the `$month` and `$monthName` variables available there now to tell you what month it's for.